# Transition probability matrix of urn model

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I have two urns: A, B. Five balls are distributed between the two urns. Each period, one of the 5 balls is selected at random, and whichever urn it's in, it is moved to the random urn. Determine the transition probability matrix.

I tried to attempt drawing the tree diagram, and I let $X_{n}$ be the number of balls in urn A at time $n$. How could I find the transition probability matrix?

Comment: In the second sentence, I assume that by "two urns" you mean "the two urns" (namely $A$ and $B$), not two urns newly introduced by this sentence as the formulation would suggest?

Comment: Yes, they are two urns namely A and B.

Comment: OK, I've added the definite article both there and before "$5$ balls" in the following sentence, where it was presumably also missing.

Comment: How about the article in "the random urn". You hadn't introduced a random urn up to this point. Presumably you mean "a random urn"?

Answer (score 2):

By Law of total probability, let $C$ be the event that randomly chosen ball is from urn $A$, $A$ and $B$ are the events that it will be placed into the urn $A$ or $B$ respectively.

The number of ball stay the same if we choose ball from $A$ and put it to $A$, or take ball from $B$ and put it to $B$:
$$
\mathbb P(X_{n+1}=n\mid X_n=n) = \mathbb P(C)\cdot \mathbb P(A\mid C)+\mathbb P(C^c)\cdot \mathbb P(B\mid C^c) = \frac{n}{5}\cdot \frac12+\frac{5 - n}{5}\cdot \frac12 = \frac12
$$
Next, the number of balls in $A$ decreased by $1$ if we take ball from $A$ and put it to $B$:
$$
\mathbb P(X_{n+1}=n-1\mid X_n=n) = \mathbb P(C)\cdot \mathbb P(B\mid C) = \frac{n}{5}\cdot \frac12= \frac{n}{10}
$$
And the number of balls in $A$ increased by $1$ if we take a ball from $B$ and put it to $A$:
$$
\mathbb P(X_{n+1}=n+1\mid X_n=n) = \mathbb P(C^c)\cdot \mathbb P(A\mid C^c) = \frac{5-n}{5}\cdot \frac12= \frac12-\frac{n}{10}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much I really appreciate your details explanation.

Comment: @DongLe  After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you could "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).